# A possible means of making an airplane invisible to radar is to coat the plane with an antireflective polymer, how thick would you make the coating?

Tags: optics, interference

A possible means of making an airplane invisible to radar is to coat the plane with an antireflective polymer. If radar waves have a wavelength of $3.00cm$ and the index of refraction of the polymer is $n = 1.50$, how thick would you make the coating?

This problem is about interference in thin films (wave optics). The answer is $0.5 cm$ using the formula $2t = (m + \frac{1}{2}) \lambda_n $ where $t$ is the thickness of the film, $m$ is an integer and $\lambda_n = \frac{\lambda}{n}$. But this is a formula for constructive interference. Should not we use destructive interference?

It is implicitly stated in most solutions that I've seen that their formula is indeed the condition for destructive interference, but my reading resources say otherwise. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think that is a formula for constructive interference?

Comment: According to my lecture notes, for constructive interference, $\delta = m \lambda_n$ or $2t - \frac{\lambda_n}{2} = m \lambda_n$. Thus, $2t = (m + \frac{1}{2}) \lambda_n$, where $m$ is an integer and $\delta$ is the path difference associated with constructive interference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical path difference between a ray being reflected from the first interface and from the second is $2t$. Each has a reflection which changes the phase by $\pi$, which therefore does not change the phase difference between the emergent rays. The condition for destructive interference is then that the physical path difference must be a half integer number of wavelengths.
$$2t = (m+0.5)\lambda$$
?

Comment: The phase shift is $\pi$ because the air's index of refraction is less than that of the coating and the plane. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Interference can redirect energy, but it cannot absorb it. So, you must back your coating with some sort of absorber. Then, the behavior depends on wavelength and geometry. It works better to use an absorber straight, without extra complication.

Comment: What do we mean by that?